# Multilingual Bibliography Entries: Apacite/Bibtex/Natbib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apacite

I am pretty new to LaTex and I am trying to figure out how to create multilingual bibliographies. Is it possible within apacite? I am not using BibLaTex, altough it's supposedly better at managing languages, because apacite fits my APA-citation-rules from university a bit better.

I am writing in German (main text, captions etc.) and my bibliography is in German as well. But for english sources I need to customize certain details (Instead of "5. Aufl." I would need "5th ed."). Is there an easy way to change this for this one source I have? Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,toc=listofnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
  \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain} 

Yada Yada

@Book{american2013diagnostic,
  title     = {Diagnostic and statistical manual of mental disorders},
  publisher = {American Psychiatric Association},
  year      = {2013},
  author    = {{{American Psychiatric Association}}},
  address   = {Arlington, VA},
  edition   = {5},
}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis1} 
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if biblatex isn't the right tool for this. In what way do your school's requirements fit apacite but not the (mature and detailed) biblatex-apa package?

Answer (score 4):

I am following up on my comment, just in case you were having trouble with the complexity of getting it working in `biblatex`, to show how it does work. So far as I know, the `biblatex-apa` style, which is "major" style, is APA-compliant, so I'd be surprised if it did not do what you need.

The key lies in the language setting for `biblatex`, and in including a field (properly `langid`, but `hyphenation` works too) which tells `biblatex` which language it should use.

Please forgive my terrible magpie-like choice of examples; I am afraid I speak neither German nor Greek!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,toc=listofnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{american2013diagnostic,
  title     = {Diagnostic and statistical manual of mental disorders},
  publisher = {American Psychiatric Association},
  year      = {2013},
  author    = {{{American Psychiatric Association}}},
  address   = {Arlington, VA},
  langid    = {english},
  edition   = {5},
}
@book{Cantor,
    author= {Cantor, Moritz.},
    title = {Vorlesungen über Geschichte der Mathematik},
    volume= {2},
    edition={2},
    address={Leipzig},
    publisher={Druck und Verlag von B.G. Teubner},
    date={1900},
    pagetotal="XII + 943 S.",
  }

@book{Vpaneta,
  author = {Συγγραφέας},
  title  = {Τίτλος},
  year   = {2012},
  langid = {greek},
  edition= {2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[language=auto,autolang=other,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
There are some works you just \emph{know} are going to turn up in a psychology paper \autocite{american2013diagnostic}. And others that are a little more surprising \autocite{Cantor}. And some that just take your breath away \autocite{Vpaneta} and make you scratch your head.

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As always, for help, `texdoc biblatex` and `texdoc biblatex-apa` are your friends.

Comment: Can I quickly draw your attention to https://github.com/PaulStanley/oscola-biblatex/pull/8 and ask if we can expect an update in the near future. (I notice that you are not listed as a watcher of your repository, so it appears quite likely to me that this just slipped past you.)

Comment: Yes. My fault. Ulrike had emailed me about it, and I just have to attend to it, but life has got away from me ... I will do it as soon as I can!