# Language-specific abbreviations for a multilingual bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Consider the following MWE, if you will:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[shorthands=off,main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} 

\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Asperger.1944,
  title = {Die „Autistischen Psychopathen“ im Kindesalter},
  author = {Asperger, Hans},
  date = {1944},
  journaltitle = {Archiv für Psychiatrie und Nervenkrankheiten},
  pages = {76--136},  
  volume = {117},
  number = {1},
  langid = {german},
}

@article{Wing.1981,
  title = {Asperger’s Syndrome. A Clinical Account.},
  author = {Wing, Lorna},
  date = {1981},
  journaltitle = {Psychological Medicine},
  pages = {115--129},
  number = {11},
  langid = {english},
}

@book{Bleuler.1911,
  title = {Dementia Præcox oder Gruppe der Schizophrenien},
  author = {Bleuler, Eugen},
  date = {1911},
  publisher = {Deuticke},
  location = {Leipzig and Wien and Heidelberg},
  langid = {german}
}

@book{McGrath.2017,
  title = {Naming Adult Autism. Culture, Science, Identity},
  author = {McGrath, James},
  date = {2017},
  publisher = {Rowman \& Littlefield},
  location = {New York and Montréal},
  isbn = {978-1-78348-040-1},
  langid = {english}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, isbn=false, doi=false, maxbibnames=99, maxitems=2, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Multiple authors separated by semicolons
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Author family name in small caps
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

% Author name followed by colon
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This almost does what I want, but it uses German abbreviations (S. = Seite(n) = page(s), e.g.) throughout. Likewise, if there is more than one publisher’s location, it uses „und“ to connect them, instead of “and”. How and where do I tell BibLatex and/or biber that the last two entries are “English”, as it were?

[image]

Comment: A  refined search turned up this lead I’ll be following: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476969/multilingual-bibliography-entries-apacite-bibtex-natbib

Comment: OK, that was embarrassingly easy: adding `language=auto, autolang=other` was all it took.

Comment: Do you want to type up and accept a quick self-answer, so this question can be marked as resolved?

Comment: Yes, thanks – I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was, in fact, quite simple: Using …

```
\usepackage[style= …
language=auto,
autolang=other, …]{biblatex}
```

… was all it took. BibLaTeX now properly formats my entries according to each language’s custom.